# Initialize MongoDB Array field in Go

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, struct, go-gin

I have this data schema:

```
"person": {
  "name": "John",
  "pets": [
    {
      "name": "Birdie"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the struct to insert the Person document to MongoDB:

```
type Person struct {
  Id   primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Pets []struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
  } `json:"pets"
}
```

When JSON is sent to the POST Person API without the pets field, the MongoDB document recorded has pets field set as null. I think this is because slices in go has zero value of nil instead of empty array?

```
personPostRequest := ds.Person{}
if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&personPostRequest); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
    return
}
```

Having pets initialized as null is troublesome because I can't use addToSet when adding pets to the document:

```
// Will render the error  Cannot apply $addToSet to non-array field.
// Field named 'pets' has non-array type null
err = collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
    ctx,
    bson.M{"_id": personId},
    bson.M{
        "$addToSet": bson.M{
            "pets": bson.M{"$each": pets},
        },
    },
    &opt,
)
```

I can solve this problem by adding the struct tag `bson:,omitempty` to pets but I like to explore the solution where I can initialized pets to empty array in MongoDB.
How do I do this in Go? I'm using Go gin framework. Thanks